# Suppose that a group $G$ contains two elements $m$ and $n$ such that $mn=nm$ and $\langle m\rangle\cap\langle n\rangle=\{e\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that a group $G$ contains two elements $m$ and $n$ such that $mn=nm$ and $\langle m\rangle\cap\langle n\rangle=\{e\}$.

Show that if $m^s\cdot n^t = e$, that $m^s=e$ and $n^t = e$.

Does $\langle m\rangle\cap\langle n\rangle=\{e\}$ mean that the two subgroups are relatively prime? To be honest I am having trouble on where to go with this.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: @TokenToucan link broken

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that $m^s \in \langle m \rangle \cap \langle n \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

The above expression implies that $n^{t}=(m^s)^{-1}\in\langle m\rangle$. Thus $n^t\in\langle m\rangle\cap\langle n\rangle$. Hence $n^t=e$, and hence also $m^s=e$.

Comment: Thats true. edited it

Answer (score 0):

If $m^sn^t=e$ then $m^s=n^{-t}$ which is an element of both subgroups $\langle m\rangle$ and $\langle n\rangle$. Since only $e$ belongs to both groups, $m^s=e=n^{ -t}$.